# Dynamic Sender Marketing Cloud

Tags: ampscript, marketing-cloud, cloud

I have Dynamic Sender Profile' functionality enabled within our business unit. I have created a sender profile encompassing verified "%%FromName%%" and %%FromEmailAddress%% which is connected with send a classification.

The below ampscript is embedded in the email which is not providing the desired output in the From email address and From name areas of the email.

```
%%[ 
VAR @FromEmailAddress
SET @FromEmailAddress = Lookup("DE TABLE","FROM_Email_ADDRESS","Email_Address", emailaddr) 
IF EMPTY (@FromEmailAddress) THEN 
    SET @FromEmailAddress = 'fallback@fallbackaddress.com' 
ENDIF
```

```
VAR @FromName
SET @FromName = Lookup("DE TABLE","Full_Name","Email_Address", emailaddr) 
IF EMPTY (@FromName) THEN 
    SET @FromName = 'CEO' 
ENDIF 
]%%
```

Note: The lookup table is not the target DE.
Am I missing a step here on the ampscript call out? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The sender profile is processed out of step with the email. Meaning anything set or declared in email will not transfer to sender profile. So those variables will be null in sender profile.

You will need to either put the ampscript directly into the  [inputs in the sender profile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/256379/12730), reference a [content block](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/232926/12730) with the ampscript in it or have it included inside the sendable data and put the correlating attributestring inside the sender profile input.

Comment: I have added 2 content boxes which are placed in the sender profile although is still not sending.
From Email section: %%=ContentBlockByKey('Snippet_From_Address')=%% 
code below:
Ex: From Email (performs a lookup to the DE where the email address is stored
%%[ 
VAR atFromEmailAddress
SET atFromEmailAddress = Lookup("Master Subscribers", "Email_Address","email", emailaddr) 
SET atFromEmailAddress = AttributeValue("Email_Address")
]%%
Here I am looking up the attribute which is also created in the profile section. at = asterisk sign to circumvent stackexchange errors

Comment: Appears From Email Address management needs every single From email to be verified before it can use the snippet inside Sender Profile.